# Issue With RETS Data Fetching Feed in PHP

Tags: php, rets, phrets, mls

I am using the PHRETS PHP library to fetch the RETS data from the rets API. I have and issue with getting the Data. It's giving me the Requested Class not found Error. Please help to solve this Error. My Code is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$log = new \Monolog\Logger('PHRETS');
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));



$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('http://rets.navicamls.net/login.aspx')
        ->setUsername('xxx')
        ->setPassword('xxx')
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');

$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
$rets->setLogger($log);

$connect = $rets->Login();


if ($connect) {
 echo "Connected!<br>";
}
else {
 echo "Not Connected!<br>";
 print_r($rets->Error());
 exit;
}


//results consists of Property, class, and query
$results = $rets->Search(
    "Property",
    "A",
    "*",
    [
        'QueryType' => 'DMQL2',
        'Count' => 1, // count and records
        'Format' => 'COMPACT-DECODED',
        'Limit' => 10,
        'StandardNames' => 0, // give system names
    ]
);

print_r($results); exit;
```

Comment: I don't know this library but I guess class A does not exists in this API :)

Comment: I am also newbie bro to use this API. Its real estate trasformation system API. from where the real estate listing we can show with Cronjob. I am nearby to my target, just stuck over it. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first verify the name of the class in your search query is correct by looking up the metadata.

1. Use [RETSMD.com](http://retsmd.com/) and enter the RETS Server login url, username, and password.
2. Use the metadata functions in the [PHRETS documentation](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) on the main page

   a. $system = $rets->GetSystemMetadata();

   b. $classes = $rets->GetClassesMetadata('Property');

Comment: I have verified the first two perameters of search function from the "RetsMD.com" as according to the metadata they are providing. But it's giving now `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHRETS\Exceptions\RETSException' with message 'Missing open parenthesis in subquery.` Fatal Error.

Comment: If you updated your code, please post it and also post the line that the error is on.

Comment: i have just changed this search function 
`$results = $rets->Search(
    'Agent',
    'Agent',
    '*',
    [
        'QueryType' => 'DMQL2',
        'Count' => 1, // count and records
        'Format' => 'COMPACT-DECODED',
        'Limit' => 99999999,
        'StandardNames' => 0, // give system names
    ]
);`

Comment: Error is `in C:\wamp\www\rets\PHRETS-master\src\Session.php on line 379`

Comment: Your code is hard to read in the comments. Please post the code in your question. You need to remove the comments "//" in your code because it may be commenting out the last right bracket and last right parenthesis.

Comment: Andrew i have solved my problem. now i have better understanding over PHRETS and DMQL. :)

Comment: @junkkrr If my answers/comments provided useful information, please vote up my answer or mark answered.

Comment: i have added useful tag to your question. but i had already tried your provided answer my own. Anyways, thanx for your time to comment it on my question. :)